# How to fill multiple live paint objects all at once in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I have multiple live paint objects that have gaps that I need to fill with color. They are bodies of water on a map, but made up of multiple strokes with gaps so Live Paint is the only way to efficiently fill them. However there are many objects. Is there a way to create a live paint group and have the fill applied to all objects all at once instead of individually clicking inside each object to fill them?

Comment: Shapebuilder may in fact be faster.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? Do all of the lines that need to be filled with the same colour have the same colour stroke?

Answer (score 1):

To paint a face, do any of the following:

Click a face to fill it. (When the pointer is over a face, it changes to a half-filled paint bucket  and highlight lines surround the inside of the fill.)

**Drag across multiple faces to paint more than one face at a time.**

Double-click a face to fill across unstroked edges into adjacent faces (flood fill).

Triple-click a face to fill all faces that currently have the same fill.

And this seemed to work better still:
**** With stroked objects after creating a livepaint group, I 'flipped' the stoke colour to the fill colour box (at base of tool bar) and all were filled with a few exceptions****

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend selecting all of the objects once you create them into live objects. This should allow you to then color all of the selected parts that you want colored.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! It's better to avoid linking to your own website unless it's very relevant - otherwise, your answer might be perceived as spam, which results in you getting banned from answering questions on GD **for good**.